# 14.04 MacBookPro tty blank screen

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, macbook-pro, tty

Installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a Macbook Pro late 2014 with a NVidia GPU (an using binary drivers), mainly following

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro11-1/Saucy

It works fine. But switching to tty consoles (fn + ctrl + alt + 1) gives me a blank screen. I commented out `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` in /etc/default/grub, but still the same.
Also get a blank screen when I switch it off.

Any body has a solution or pointer to this?

Thanks a lot,

Seb

Comment: I guess there won't be an answer. There are many similar questions with tags nvidia tty. I went through pretty all of them. Have to live with no tty terminal for now. The problem when things breaks... will allow ssh to it, so can log in from another computer... best I can come up with so far.

Answer (score 0):

I went back to the nouveau drivers and tty works again (MBP 11,3 late 2013). Now trying to decide if i prefer nvidia drivers or working tty :s

Comment: I have now gone back to nvidia drivers - i can live without tty. With nouveau drivers i found it more annoying that when i locked the screen the display did not power off (just went black). I noticed that in tty i can still login and issue commands (like sudo reboot) just can't see what I type ;)